# How to calculate percentage of a number in Java?

Tags: java, math, percentage

I will try to be as simple as possible:

Let´s assume I have an `Integer discount` and a `long price`.

Is there any efficient way to do this manually?

Is there any Java utility (in `Math` package, for instance) that calculate the `price` after the `discount`?

Comment: Please.. you don't need a library to calculate a discount...

Comment: `long discountedPrice = (long) Math.round(price * (1.0 - discount / 100.0));`

Comment: Unless those variables store cents, you'd be better using `BigDecimal` to store currency

Answer (score 4):

Really, Do you need a library function for it ?

Do some maths by own.

```
discountedPrice = price - (discount * price) / 100.0
```